# can't add reference to System.xml.linq.dll as it is not built against silverlight runtime

Tags: silverlight

I am using System.Xml.Linq

But is unable to add an reference to it, the following error appears whenever I tried adding the reference from Microsoft framework

"can't add reference to System.xml.linq.dll as it is not built against silverlight runtime."

I am using Visual Studio 2010, silverlight 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably picking the wrong version. There is one for Silverlight and one for "regular" .NET. Here is a similar [question](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/98380/225942.aspx).

They added a reference to the Silverlight version in `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Client\"`. But you'd want either `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client"` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client"`, dpending on if you are on a 64-bit machine.